# Self-isolate if my home country rises above threshold while I'm in Latvia?

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, latvia

The current [regulations to enter Latvia](https://www.mfa.gov.lv/en/consular-information/news/66019-emergency-situation-in-latvia-to-restrict-the-spread-of-covid-19) from another EU country mandate that I have to self-isolate for 14 days on arrival if the country I am coming from has had more than 16 new Covid cases per 100k inhabitants in the past 14 days; the [infection rates for each country](https://www.spkc.gov.lv/lv/valstu-saslimstibas-raditaji-ar-covid-19-0) are updated every Friday and are valid for the successive week.

Suppose that my country of origin is below the threshold when I enter Latvia, but gets above the threshold in the next update the following Friday, while I am already inside Latvia.

Do I have to report myself to the authorities and self-isolate? Or is that requirement only checked when I enter Latvia?

Comment: Since while *inside Latvia* you were **not** in (or traveled through in transit) a country with a high infection rate, the conditions for peaple who ***arrived* from countries in which the 14-day cumulative number of COVID-19 cases has exceeded 16 individuals per 100,000** do not apply to you.

Comment: I'm sure no country imposes such a rule

Comment: @Crazydre In many countries the rules are written as "if you have been in one of these countries in the past 14 days, then you have to enter quarantine". With that wording, I'd have to self-isolate.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Nope, it means if you've been to such a country in the past 14 days **upon entering the country**. No country, I assure you, retroactively requires you to enter self-isolation. It's either upon entering the country, or not at all. Which is plain logic; they're worried about the infection rates in your departure country at the time you were actually there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is over and this question is no longer of relevance.